# Jackson CSV modeler for composite class

Tags: java, csv, jackson

Consider Person and Address classes as:

```
class Person {

    String name;
    int age;
    Address first;
    Address second;
}

class Address {

    String country;
    String city;

}
```

I want to parse csv file to Person objects. sample csv file is:

```
NAME,AGE,COUNTERY_1,CITY_1,COUNTRY_2,CITY_2
john,50,USA,Arizona,UK,London
bob,27,France,paris,USA,Felorida
```

I write a model method:

```
CsvSchema bootstrapSchema = CsvSchema.emptySchema().withHeader();
CsvMapper mapper = new CsvMapper();
MappingIterator<Person> readValues = mapper
            .readerWithTypedSchemaFor(Person.class)
            .with(bootstrapSchema)
            .readValues(file);
return readValues.readAll();
```

How to add Address class mapping to mapper?

Answer (score 2):

You can't really do this with Jackson, but [univocity-parsers](https://www.univocity.com/pages/parsers-tutorial) can with its `@Nested` annotation:

First define your `Address` class like this:

```
public static class Address {
    @Parsed
    String country;
    @Parsed
    String city;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Address{country='" + country + '\'' + ", city='" + city + '\'' + '}';
    }
}
```

Now if you look at your input, we need to somehow associate the headers "country_1" and "city_1" with the fields in your `Address` class. This is done using a custom `HeaderTransformer` class that appends the index to the header name. Let's define it like this:

```
public static class SuffixAppender extends HeaderTransformer {

    private String suffix;

    public SuffixAppender(String... args) {
        suffix = args[0];
    }

    @Override
    public String transformName(Field field, String name) {
        return name + "_" + suffix;
    }
}
```

Now you can define your `Person` class with nested `Address` attributes:

```
public static class Person {
    @Parsed
    String name;

    @Parsed
    int age;

    @Nested(headerTransformer = SuffixAppender.class, args = "1")
    Address first;

    @Nested(headerTransformer = SuffixAppender.class, args = "2")
    Address second;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person{name='" + name + '\'' + ", age=" + age + ", first=" + first + ", second=" + second + '}';
    }
}
```

The above instructs the parser to get the field names in `Address` and append the given suffix to it with your `SuffixAppender`. The result will be matched against the headers of your input.

Finally you are ready to parse. There are many ways to use the parser, but the simplest is:

```
String input = "" +
        "NAME,AGE,COUNTRY_1,CITY_1,COUNTRY_2,CITY_2\n" +
        "john,50,USA,Arizona,UK,London\n" +
        "bob,27,France,paris,USA,Florida";

CsvParserSettings settings = new CsvParserSettings(); //configure the parser
settings.detectFormatAutomatically(); //detects line separators and delimiters

//parse the input with the settings above, into a list of Person objects    
List<Person> personList = new CsvRoutines(settings).parseAll(Person.class, new StringReader(input));
```

Let's see the result with:

```
Person person1 = personList.get(0);
Person person2 = personList.get(1);
System.out.println(person1);
System.out.println(person2);
```

Output:

```
Person{name='john', age=50, first=Address{country='USA', city='Arizona'}, second=Address{country='UK', city='London'}}
Person{name='bob', age=27, first=Address{country='France', city='paris'}, second=Address{country='USA', city='Florida'}}
```

Hope it helps.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of this library. It's open source and free (Apache 2.0 license)